# Understanding ajax gallery and categories

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make category based gallery with ajax/php/mysql. On the index page are loaded bunch of images. They have href link to the page where user can see only selected image from that category. Now I want to make two buttons for next and prev links so the user can navigate to next image **from that category**.

The problem is that I'm not sure that I understand it how exactly work the ajax part and how I can "give" the category ID.

This is the link from the index page

```
<a href="test.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].'"></a>
```

This is on the `test.php`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $.post( "getpicture.php", { img_category: "1"}, function( data ) {
     $(".main-post").html( data );
   });

   $(".main-post").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
       var image_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
     $(".main-post").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
     $.post( "getpicture.php", {  img_category: 1 }, function( data ) {
     $(".main-post").html( data );
   });
   return false;
   });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <article class="main-post">
     // HERE THE IMAGE IS LOADED
   </article>
</body>
```

This is the source in getpicture.php

```
//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["img_category"]) && is_numeric($_POST["img_category"]))
{
    $current_picture = filter_var($_POST["img_category"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_picture=1;
}
//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){  
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id > $current_picture ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result){
   $next_id = $result->image_id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id < $current_picture ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
   $prev_id = $result->image_id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_name, image_title, image_hits FROM images WHERE img_category =  $current_picture LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){

  //construct next/previous button
  $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_pic"><img src="prev.png" border="0" /></a>':'';
  $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_pic"><img src="next.png" border="0" /></a>':'';

//output html
echo '
      <h1><a href="#">'.$result->image_title.'</a></h1>
        <div class="pull-right">
         '.$prev_button.'
         '.$next_button.'
        </div>
        <div class="article-content">
           <img  src="upload/'.$result->image_name.'" alt=""/>            
        </div>';    
}
```

It's clear that I'm kind of new in this field and still learning but can't understand this.

Right now I click on image with `ID=431` on `test.php` is loaded first row from database `id=1` and when I click on next button doesn't change anything.. just refreshing the image that is current.

UPDATE: image table structure

```
image_id
image_name
image_type
image_size
image_alt
image_path
img_category
```

image_category table

```
category_id
category_name
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have defined **var image_id = $(this).attr('data-id');** and never used, you have to pass this image_id to your ajax post.

```
$.post( "getpicture.php", {  img_category: 1, imageId: image_id }, function( data ) {
     $(".main-post").html( data );
   });
```

And second your **$current_picture** value doesn't depend by $_POST[img_category] which will have always the same value, in this case 1 it's depends by $_POST["image_id"]

```
$current_picture = $_POST["imageId"];
$currentCategory = $_POST["img_category"];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id > $current_picture and image_category=$currentCategory ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
```

and so on for your next query, be carefully you must have an **image_category** field in your database table

This scripts is a good start for learning, consider using firebug add on  for firefox or developer console already installed chrome for a easy way to track  ajax requests

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I still don't understand how the ajax and getpicture.php will know what category is?

Comment: maybe there are some errors, i didn't test this code
and for first comment you have to add another attribute to your image, like you did with image-id data-category="$result->category_id"

Answer (score 0):

You are always send the same 'img_category' value. That's the mistake. Try to use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var imageUrl = 'getpicture.php';
        var $mainPost = $(".main-post");

        var showLoader = function () {
            $mainPost.html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
        };

        var getImage = function (id) {                
            var data = {
                img_category: (typeof id !== 'undefined') ? id : 1
            };

            showLoader();
            $.post(imageUrl, data, function( data ) {
                $mainPost.html(data);
            });
        };

        getImage();

        $mainPost.on("click", ".get_pic", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            getImage($(this).attr('data-id'));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank's. With this is loaded again 1 id from database. When click on next button is showing next image and if pres second time next button is showing blank page.

Comment: Can you provide the `images` table structure?